# Como pegar a data de criação de um arquivo que está em um servidor FTP c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, sftp

Estou usando framework 4.5 e gostaria de saber como faço para pegar a data e hora de criação de um arquivo que está em um servidor SFTP, não quero fazer o download dele, apenas saber a data e a hora que ele foi criado.

Eu tenho permissão de leitura da pasta e do arquivo, o usuário e senha do SFTP.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, você não precisa de um componente extra para fazer as operações que constam na resposta do **`pho3nix`**, é possível fazer tudo com o .NET "puro", ainda mais uma operação simples como a que deseja. E mais, o pacote **`Ftp.dll`** é **pago**, talvez você não tenha notado isso, mas é só entrar no site deles que dá pra ver a seguinte mensagem.

> This download is fully functional trial. It has the same features as the registered version. The evaluation version of the component displays "Please purchase a license" dialog. Some uploaded files will have their name changed. To remove this limitation you'll need to purchase a license.

Segundo, a resposta esta errada, pelo menos segundo a descrição da sua pergunta. SFTP e FTPS são duas coisas **completamente diferentes**. Resumidamente:

- **FTPS** é o protocolo FTP com a adição de SSL, para segurança.
- **SFTP** (SSH File Transfer Protocol/Secure File Transfer Protocol) é uma extensão do SSH que fornece a capacidade de transferência de arquivos.

Neste caso, você vai mesmo precisar de um pacote extra para auxiliar. Eu achei o [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET), faz um bom tempo que não é mexido, mas é open source e é possível tirar o máximo de proveito dele. Testei ele usando meu servidor e funcionou bem, aqui vai um exemplo de como fazer

```
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(servidor, porta, usuario, senha))
{
    sftp.Connect();

    DateTime data = sftp.GetLastWriteTime("caminhoDoArquivoNoServidor");

    sftp.Disconnect();
}
```

Talvez seja interessante você [procurar por algum pacote no nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=SFTP)

Answer (score 0):

Terá que usar um componente de [Ftp](http://www.limilabs.com/ftp/download)

para instalar:

```
Install-Package Ftp.dll
```

Depois no seu código

```
// C# version

using (Ftp client = new Ftp())
{
    client.Connect("ftp.example.org");    // or ConnectSSL for SSL
    client.Login("user", "password");

    List<FtpItem> items = client.GetList();

    foreach (FtpItem item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name:        {0}", item.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Size:        {0}", item.Size);
        Console.WriteLine("Modify date: {0}", item.ModifyDate);

        Console.WriteLine("Is folder:   {0}", item.IsFolder);
        Console.WriteLine("Is file:     {0}", item.IsFile);
        Console.WriteLine("Is symlink:  {0}", item.IsSymlink);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    client.Close();
}
```

Comment: Tentei usar esse código mas ele da exceção com o erro `O nome solicitado é válido, mas não foram encontrados dados do tipo solicitado` na linha `client.Connect("ftp.example.org")`, sabe o que pode ser ?

Comment: Pode ser uma pergunta estupida mas trocou o ftp.example.org pelo seu ftp?

Comment: Troquei sim, coloquei o meu ftp e inclusive vi que o método `Connect` tem um dos parâmetros para colocar a porta e eu coloquei a porta para acessar o meu ftp

Comment: Peço desculpa pela pergunta, mas muitas vezes acontece. Por acaso acho que tem que usar a função ConnectSSL ( // or ConnectSSL for SSL) porque é um SFTP

Comment: Sem problemas. Então... mesmo assim não funcionou, deu o mesmo erro usei o ConnectSSL e não funcionou, tentei até usar o BeginConnect() mas tbm não funcionou.

Comment: Acabei de testar no meu pc e com o meu ftp esta ok.

Comment: Acho que é válido lembrar que esse componente é pago. E também que é possível fazer isso sem ele, o que sua resposta não explica.